# while building SAAS solutions based on Corda, who owns the certificates issued to each participant?

Tags: blockchain, corda

while building SAAS solutions based on Corda, who owns the certificates issued to each participant? Is it owned by SAAS provider / each node?

Answer (score 1):

The Corda nodes receive their digital certificates from the Certificate Authority of the Corda network they participate to, the *Identity Manager*, which in turns receive its certificate from the network root. With this certificate from the CA, the Corda node can participate to the network and it can also use it to sign its own certificates.

So, to answer your question: it depends on the extent of the Corda SAAS solution provided. If this service provides also its own private Corda network, which means it also handles the Identity Manager and root network, then the SAAS provider owns these certificates. Otherwise, if the SAAS provides only a *Node-as-a-Service* connected to the public-permissioned Corda Network (ran by the Corda Network Foundation, or in general another subzone ran by a third party), then the certificates are issued (and also checked and revocated) by the CA of that network.

I invite you to read the documentation about [Network Certificates](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/permissioning.html), the [Certificate Hierarchy](https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.5/pki-guide.html#certificate-hierarchy-guide) in the CENM (Corda Enterprise Network Manager) documentation, and also how it works with the [Network Foundation](https://trust.corda.network/trust-root/certificate-policy.html).

Comment: in case of own private Corda network, considering HSM in cloud. what happens if in future the keys have to be regenerated? how does that affect the identity of the node?